# How to show Seven Segment display in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to show the `TextBox` font style like seven segment display in windows application?

```
textBox.Font="22:30:40";
txtxbox.Font.Style=FontStyle. ?;
```

Comment: You download and use an LCD styled font face after googling for *free lcd font* - You cannot do this by setting a style.

Comment: with style you can set bold, italic etc. To use font like the one you want, download it and use in your application. take look at free fonts [here](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=302)

Comment: After download how to add or use it in my application? @ Nino

Comment: [PrivateFontCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection)

Comment: @Sathishkumar Please find the Updated Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are looking to apply bit difficult.

This is how it should be

1. Install the required font. In your case you can download the font from 
   http://www.keshikan.net/fonts-e.html. its just for example purpose.
2. Install the Font and you will see it in ControlPanel>Fonts like shown below Please install all the regular italic and other available otherwise it will throw error later on.
   [image]
3. Now in your C# Code you can create a FONT like given.

   ```
   var  segmentFont= new Font("DSEG7 Modern", 14);
   ```
4. Apply whatever the style you want Like Italics Bold regular whatever.
   Please ensure all font style are installed otherwise exception will be thrown.

**Your Final code will be something like this**

```
var  segmentFont= new Font("DSEG7 Modern", 14);
textBox.Font=segmentFfont;
```

For optimization you can create a global font.

Comment: Thanks @Ramankingdom ...It works fine..But my doubt is if i load my setup in other computer how it will work ..? or i need to save the font in control panel in that system .?

Comment: you can ship the font with installer and install that as well. The other way of doing is to load the font at run time and show it. If you have access to install the font put in installer. otherwise there is article available on stackoverflow How to load font at runtime in c# which you can use. Please dont forget to mark it as answer as well.